# Wordpress User-meta plugin how to display user registration form if user already logged in

Tags: wordpress

For example, if I have two levels at which a user logs-in, `user level 1`, and `user level 2`; where `user level 1` has registered himself, and after verification and `user level 1` logs-in; now the `user level 1` pages should show a `user level 2` registration form.

I am getting an error stating that user is already logged in when I am trying to display `user level 2` registration form.

```
 [user-meta-registration form="Business Users Registration"]
```

Comment: so how do you implement the registration process? a plugin or what?

Comment: Hi. I thought  would let you know that I did some formatting, and grammar updates on your post. First, I formatted the login forum names.